# Using HAVING or WHERE on SUM Fields

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, where-clause, having

**Problem**

We have a Users table and a Addresses table.Each user can have multiple addresses. We have a bit field called **`IsDefault`** where a user can select their default address. This field currently isnt mandatory and possibly will be in the future, so I need to do some analysis. Now I want to validate the addresses to see:

- How many addresses a given user has.
- How many of those addresses (if they have more than 1 address) have
  the IsDefault flag set to a 1.

Basically I want to see how many of my users who have multiple addresses, **have not switched on** any of their addresses to be their default.

I have the following SQL query so far:

```
SELECT  AD.User_Id,
        COUNT(AD.User_Id) AS HowManyAddresses,
        SUM(
            CASE WHEN 
                AD.IsDefault IS NULL 
                OR
                AD.IsDefault = 0
            THEN
                1
            ELSE
                0
            END
        ) AS DefaultEmpty,

        SUM(
            CASE WHEN 
                AD.IsDefault = 1
            THEN
                1
            ELSE
                0
            END
        ) AS DefaultAddress

FROM dbo.Addresses AS AD
    JOIN dbo.Users AS U
    ON U.Id = AD.User_Id
GROUP BY AD.User_ID
ORDER BY AD.User_Id
```

The problem I have found is I want to check the values from the `DefaultAddress` and `DefaultEmpty` SELECT SUM fields, but I get the following error when trying to reference them using WHERE or HAVING:

> Invalid column name 'DefaultEmpty'.

Is it not possible to reference SUM values for selection purposes?

**Technology using:**

1. SQL Server 2008
2. SQL Server Management Studio 2008

Comment: It is possible to use SUM values, but you cannot refer to column aliases in the where or having clauses, so you would have to retype the aggregate, e.g. `HAVING SUM(CASE WHEN AD.IsDefault IS NULL OR AD.IsDefault = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) > 1`. The `SELECT` clause is after the `WHERE/HAVING` clause with in the [Logical Processing Order](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189499.aspx) therefore when both are executed those columns aliases have not yet been defined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually you need to repeat the whole `SUM` clause with `HAVING` like this -

```
SELECT
    AD.User_Id
    ,COUNT(AD.User_Id) AS HowManyAddresses
    ,SUM(
    CASE
        WHEN
            AD.IsDefault IS NULL OR
            AD.IsDefault = 0 THEN 1
        ELSE 0
    END
    ) AS DefaultEmpty
    ,SUM(
    CASE
        WHEN
            AD.IsDefault = 1 THEN 1
        ELSE 0
    END
    ) AS DefaultAddress

FROM dbo.Addresses AS AD
JOIN dbo.Users AS U
    ON U.Id = AD.User_Id
GROUP BY AD.User_ID
HAVING SUM(
CASE
    WHEN
        AD.IsDefault IS NULL OR
        AD.IsDefault = 0 THEN 1
    ELSE 0
END
) = 0
ORDER BY AD.User_Id
```

OR

```
DECLARE @address TABLE(UserID INT,Address VARCHAR(100),IsDefault BIT);
INSERT INTO @address VALUES
 (1,'User 1 default',1)
,(2,'User 2 non default',0)
,(3,'User 3 non default',0)
,(3,'User 3 default',1)
,(4,'User 4 default',1)
,(4,'User 4 second default',1);

SELECT
    COUNT(*) OVER () AS HowManyAddresses
    ,ISNULL(def0.DefaultEmpty, 0) AS DefaultEmpty
    ,ISNULL(def1.DefaultAddress, 0) AS DefaultAddress
FROM (SELECT
        AD.Address
        ,COUNT(AD.UserID) OVER (PARTITION BY AD.UserID) AS DefaultEmpty
    FROM @address AS AD
    WHERE (AD.IsDefault = 0)) def0
FULL JOIN (SELECT
        AD.Address
        ,COUNT(AD.UserID) OVER (PARTITION BY AD.UserID) AS DefaultAddress
    FROM @address AS AD
    WHERE (AD.IsDefault = 1)) def1
    ON def0.Address = def1.Address
```

Answer (score 1):

This will count - grouped by user and default, how many addresses there are:

```
DECLARE @user TABLE(ID INT, Name VARCHAR(100));
INSERT INTO @user VALUES
 (1,'user1') --will get a default
,(2,'user2') --no default
,(3,'user3') --both
,(4,'user4') --two defaults
,(5,'user5');--nothing

DECLARE @address TABLE(UserID INT,Address VARCHAR(100),IsDefault BIT);
INSERT INTO @address VALUES
 (1,'User 1 default',1)
,(2,'User 2 non default',0)
,(3,'User 3 non default',0)
,(3,'User 3 default',1)
,(4,'User 4 default',1)
,(4,'User 4 second default',1);
```

EDIT: Better with PIVOT...

```
SELECT p.*
FROM
(
    SELECT u.ID,u.Name
          ,CASE WHEN a.IsDefault=1 THEN 'DEFAULT' ELSE 'NORMAL' END AS PivotColumn
          ,COUNT(a.UserID) AS CountPerUserAndDefault
    FROM @user AS u
    LEFT JOIN @address AS a ON u.ID=a.UserID
    GROUP BY u.ID,u.Name,a.IsDefault
) AS tbl
PIVOT
(
    SUM(CountPerUserAndDefault) FOR PivotColumn IN([DEFAULT],[NORMAL])
) AS p
```

The result:

```
Name    ID  DEFAULT NORMAL
user1   1   1       NULL
user2   2   NULL    1
user3   3   1       1
user4   4   2       NULL
user5   5   NULL    0
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `CTE` in following if you want to use alias names in `WHERE` clause:

```
WITH cte AS (
SELECT  AD.User_Id,
        COUNT(AD.User_Id) AS HowManyAddresses,
        SUM(
            CASE WHEN 
                AD.IsDefault IS NULL 
                OR
                AD.IsDefault = 0
            THEN
                1
            ELSE
                0
            END
        ) AS DefaultEmpty,

        SUM(
            CASE WHEN 
                AD.IsDefault = 1
            THEN
                1
            ELSE
                0
            END
        ) AS DefaultAddress

FROM dbo.Addresses AS AD
    JOIN dbo.Users AS U
    ON U.Id = AD.User_Id
GROUP BY AD.User_ID
ORDER BY AD.User_Id
)
SELECT * 
FROM cte
WHERE /* You can use alias names here... */
GROUP BY /* You can use alias names here... */
HAVING /* You can use alias names here... */
```

Answer (score 0):

Put this after `GROUPBY`:

```
HAVING SUM(CAST(AD.IsDefault AS INT)) > 0
```